# Объявление публичных переменных в PHP

Tags: ооп, php, переменные

Стоит ли объявлять в классе публичные переменные, если их значение по умолчанию не задается, а получается извне? Если да, то зачем? Они же публичные, их можно передать прямо в метод.

```
class Example {

    public $city; /*Нужно ли объявлять здесь переменную?*/

    function getData ($city) {
        ...
    }
}

$city = "London";
$obj = new Example;
$obj -> getData($city);
```

Comment: При номальном подходе переменные не задаются (почти не задаются) вне классов, потому стОит обьявлять

Comment: Пользователь будет передавать в функцию произвольные данные. Например - название города. А функция будет выводить в ответ, скажем, страну где этот город находится. По умолчанию название города в классе не задается. Оно всегда получается извне. Но и метод тоже публичный. И тоже всегда вызывается извне. Так зачем объявлять переменную? Если надо - то объясните зачем.

UPD: Я понял, что вы имеете ввиду. Что данные, введенные пользователем можно забрать из базы, из суперглобального массива и т.п. Но если именно такой код, как написан выше, стоит объявлять или нет?

Comment: @qtm, это **не** переменная, это свойство объекта. Если метод использует аргумент только для расчета чего-то и не записывает его в одноименное свойство, то ничего объявлять не надо.

Comment: @qtm, представьте - я работаю с вашим классом. Если $city где-то еще используется, то как я узнаю о том, что он есть и что это такое, если вы его не объявите?

Выискивать по коду где, что и как используется?

А вот если не только объявите, но и комментарием его снабдите, то IDE при работе с данной переменной подскажет что это и как ее можно использовать (например, если $city - объект какого-то класса).

А вот зачем он вам как public - это другой вопрос. Если не хотите чтобы был доступ к $city извне, то может быть стоит объявить его как protected (или даже private)?

Comment: @ВОРОН если вы снабдите описание метода коментарием, то ide его тоже подхватит и будет подсказывать.

Comment: @eicto, так мы про свойства говорим. Или если я в методе опишу переменную класса, то IDE подхватит?

    ...
    public function a() {
        /* $this->_a Exception */
        $this->_a = new Exception();
    }
    ...

Если не через $this, то подхватит в пределах метода. А вот для $this - не знаю, я почти голым npp пользуюсь )))

И в любом случае - если мне надо будет описание подправить - искать где же оно (описание) в методах находится?

Когда все на виду - как-то надежнее будет.

И еще - если я не вижу переменную в описании класса, то я скорее всего ее заведу, а потом баги ловить буду?

Comment: @eicto, понял про что вы.

Если ТС имел ввиду переменную метода, тогда ему достаточно будет комментария тов. @Etki.

Я же исходил из того, что $city необходимо классу, а не методу. Т.е. что-то типа:

    class Test {
        public $a; // можно не объявлять, но не очевидно будет
        public function check($a) {
            $this->a = $a;
        }
        public function check2($b = '123') {
            print $b;
        }
    }
    $test = new Test();
    $test->a = 123;
    $test->check(321);

А Т.С., наверное, имел ввиду что-то типа метода check2.

Comment: Да, я имел ввиду метод check2. Если метод изменяет и записывает переменную, как нужную - тогда ее стоит объявлять. А если она просто используется в методе - тогда нет? 
Хорошо, а если говорить просто о красивом коде, то может быть тогда стоит все переменные записывать как в методе сheck?